# Unpredictable hair particles in shallow surface

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to model a feather using hair particles. Ideally, the hair would follow a direction similar to the normals in the shaft, going out and away from the center. However, by the tip of the shaft, it starts to become unpredictable the direction the hairs will take.

[image: Viewport image of the tip of two feathers, both presenting the issue described above]

I tried creating the particle system in a much thicker shaft (like the one in the right) and later scaling it down in edit mode. It worked when creating the parent particles, but the children still present the issue, and grooming doesn't help. (the one in the left has grooming).

I'm assuming this is because the shaft is thin, so the normals get averaged and it decides to go to the other side. No idea how to fix this tho.

Extra info:

- All normals are correctly pointing to the outside.
- I have a vertex group along the borders of the shaft for the density of the hair.
- Using blender 2.92.0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tip of the feather is a single vertex. This creates triangles and messes the particles up. Delete it. Then just extrude and scale down the last edge loop.

[image: tips]

[image: particles]