# How do you tweak the length of children hair's interpolation between parent gradually?

Tags: particles, hair

Blender 3.6
[image]

I'm trying to make a feather using hair particle but the hair length of children between the parent interpolates in an unpredictable manner.

[image: Sample expected feather base(below) and the hair particle(above)]
[image: Parent hair]

I've read [Unpredictable hair particles in shallow surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247568/unpredictable-hair-particles-in-shallow-surface) but it doesn't answer the question.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make the hair length of children between parent change gradually so that the curve is smooth and not bumpy. Is there a way to do so or are there any better solution?